# is it possible to create react app and deploy in sharepoint online without creating as web part?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

has anyone worked with react and sharepoint, please tell me, if there any reference for creating a react app and deploy in sharepoint online directly, many of the references are creating react app as web part, but I cant find what I looking for. please help

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on where you want your application to show up in the SharePoint.

In addition to the WebParts, there is AppCustomizer option that allows you to show your app in one dedicated the placeholder of the sharepoint site (top or bottom):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions

Other that, there is "single page part" option that allows you app to occupy all the space on the page, and to be the only thing the user gets basically:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages?tabs=pnpposh

Comment: thanks for the info Nik, I saw the single page part option that's look fine, but header menu are coming from  sharepoint by default. My requirement is my app needs occupy entire screen including the header, so whatever I create in React application I need to display it in entirely in sharepoint. Just like creating in React app and hosting in sharepoint.. any idea on this?

Comment: If you don't need to integrate with SharePoint then you could just dump your javascript files to a SharePoint library and use sharepoint as a static file hosting (i.e. a folder). Just rename the index.html to index.aspx, put it in /SiteAssets (or whatever you choose) and you should be good to go. In SharePoint, you can add a link to your index.aspx page to the navigation.

Comment: BTW, you don't need SPFx to accomplis this as well :)